# Experience Editor Yellow Screen After Timeout

Tags: experience-editor

If user times out in Experience Editor, it fails ungracefully with a yellow screen on refresh.  This happens even if user subsequently re-logs into Sitecore.

[image: Yellow Screen]

We are considering increasing the timeout, but are curious if this is a known issue. Where would the timeout be increased, if we went that direction?

Sitecore 8.2 Update-4 (rev. 170614)

Comment: In the web.config there is a setting
`<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />`

You can increase the value for timeout.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778952/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bl?

Comment: will that happens if the user opened a new tab/window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug by Sitecore. The bug reference number is 191728. This occurs when using a cshtml file as the file that your layout points to. [Here is the download link](https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/t7q6y7e4majnzc009ow82w8ulxv163ge) for the instance I had this issue in (Sitecore CMS 8.2 rev. 170614 Update-4).