# Sitecore login - The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: experience-editor, login

I got the following exception when the Sitecore instance jump to the **login page with the following querystring**: `<domain>/sitecore/login?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=%7b11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111%7d&sc_version=1&sc_lang=en&sc_site=website`

If I remove `sc_itemid` parameter then it works fine. If I change the `sc_itemid` to other item IDs then it works in some cases but it does not work some other cases.

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection
>   cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <%
>   ... %>).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be
>   modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).]
>   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.AddAt(Int32 index, Control child) +502
>   Sitecore.Layouts.PageContext.InsertUnusedControls() +245 (Object ,
>   Object[] ) +74 Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>   +469 Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Layouts.PageContext.BuildControlTree(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) +217 System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +138
>   System.Web.UI.d__495.MoveNext() +199
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +32
>   System.Web.UI.d__523.MoveNext() +2189

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are on? if 8+, did yo have a look at the question below: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blo

Comment: @AmitabhVyas Yes, i had a look and the stack trace is different so I decided to open a new question. It happens on version 8.2.